# How do send the actual control id of an UpdatePanel to an UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ScriptAction script?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I need to send the actual control id that .NET generates for an UpdatePanel's div to a javascript function. How do I rewrite the **ScriptAction** line below to accomplish this?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="update1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    ...
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<cc1:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="update1">
    <Animations>
        <OnUpdating>
            <Parallel duration="0">
                <ScriptAction Script="doSomething(**update1's ID**);" />
            </Parallel>
        </OnUpdating>
        ...
    </Animations>
</cc1:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>
```

**EDIT**:

I would like to have `update1.UniqueId` be placed in `doSomething`'s parameters.

**EDIT**:

The following fails:

```
<ScriptAction Script="alert('<%= update1.ClientID %>');" />
```

With

```
 Exception type: System.Web.HttpParseException
 Exception message: The 'Animations' property of 'cc1:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender' does not allow child objects.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use its ClientID?

```
Script="doSomething('<%= update1.ClientID %>');"
```

According to your updated question: add this ClientID as a javascript variable at the top of the page. Then you can access it from your js-function.

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  var update1ClientID = '<%= update1.ClientID %>';</script>
```

and then:

```
Script="doSomething('' + update1ClientID );"
```

If this also doesn't work, try to use the same approach but from Codebehind(Page_Load)

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me.Page).RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType, "update1ClientID", "var update1ClientID='" & Me.update1.ClientID & "';", True)
```

Comment: Yeah this would work but unfortunately for me the updatepanel is inside a custom control and there could be more than one per page. I will accept your answer however because it would work otherwise.

Comment: ^^: I don't know what your `doSomething`-function does, but can't you register that function via RegisterClientScriptBlock and add the UpdatePanel's ClientID inside of that function with `'<%= update1.ClientID %>'`? On this way you wouldn't need to pass the id as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ScriptAction Script="doSomething('<%=update1.ClientID %>');" />
```

** Edit ***

To add to Tim's solution, if you have more than one custom control per page, iterate through the page controls and add a register script for each control that is of the type of your custom control.